# How can access the data recieved from API outside of this function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have used node.js and request.js to access form information from our email services API. With the console.log in the function I am able to see all the info that I need. I have tried to access it outside of the function with dot notation(request.missionStatement) which I don't think is right. I want to be able to display this on a page within an express.js app.

```
var request = require('request');  

//  Basic Authentication credentials  
var username = "user";  
var password = "password";  
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");  

// Search for Custom Data Objects Affiliate Falculty form 
request(  
{  
    url : "url to api",  
    headers : { "Authorization" : authenticationHeader }  
},  
function (error, response, body) {  
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);//convert text from API to JSON file
    var missionStatement = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.elements.length ; i++) {                
        var individualStatement = "";
        //Get text submission from form and push into array
        individualStatement += (parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[4].value + ",  " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[2].value + " " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[3].value + ",  " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[0].value);
        missionStatement.push(individualStatement);
     };
    console.log(missionStatement)  
}
```

);

Comment: Sorry forgot to ask my question. How do i access the missionStatement array outside of the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable **missionStatement** is a local variable declared inside an anonymous function passed as an argument to the request function, and thus it is inaccessible once the anonymous function returns. You must save your result elsewhere. Try something like this:

```
var request = require('request');  

//  Basic Authentication credentials  
var username = "user";  
var password = "password";  
var authenticationHeader = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");

var result;

// Search for Custom Data Objects Affiliate Falculty form 
request(  
{  
    url : "url to api",  
    headers : { "Authorization" : authenticationHeader }  
},  
function (error, response, body) {  
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(body);//convert text from API to JSON file
    var missionStatement = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < parsedData.elements.length ; i++) {                
        var individualStatement = "";
        //Get text submission from form and push into array
        individualStatement += (parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[4].value + ",  " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[2].value + " " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[3].value + ",  " + parsedData.elements[i].fieldValues[0].value);
        missionStatement.push(individualStatement);
     };
    result = missionStatement;
    displayResult();
});

function displayResult() {
    console.log(result);
}
```

Your **missionStatement** will now be saved in **result**, but only after the anonymous callback to request() has been called (when the actual request is finished).

Comment: While this will work, I would like to add that you should probably not be doing it like that. A more correct way would be to pass the data you need (missionStatement) directly to whatever needs that data. Example: If you want to print out the data on a page, have the callback function do it directly or call another function that prints out the data. Don't save it in a global variable unless you really need to. Doing so was just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks Mark! This is my first time using Express. I'm assuming I would put my entire function inside the routing for the particular page I need it to display it on. I will give it a whirl.